# AngularJS: ui-select once selected not able to remove selected option apart from change option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-select

I am using ui-select for fetching data from server & populate it in drop down (search & select). I created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/00v6KVulXtofRCyo2o4u?p=preview) for you.

```
<ui-select ng-model="country.selected" theme="selectize" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 300px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search a country in the list...">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="country in countries | filter: $select.search">
        <span ng-bind-html="country.name | highlight: $select.search"></span>
        <small ng-bind-html="country.code | highlight: $select.search"></small>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Once I selected any value from selector, I can change further. But not able to remove. How can I do this?

Comment: 'Not able to remove' remove what? The selected from the `select`? Or from the displayed selected item?

Comment: @devqon selected from the select

Comment: I wanted to set back like no option selected

Comment: Then just reset `country.selected`? `<button ng-click="country.selected = null">Remove</button>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use an other theme like `select2` to make this work. I upgraded your [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/4rPYRMgiOVYCLCFWaUvK?p=preview) to show how this could work. Add `allow-clear="true"` into `ui-select-match` and set theme to `theme="select2"` to allow unselect an item.

```
<ui-select ng-model="country.selected" 
           theme="select2" 
           ng-disabled="disabled">
      <ui-select-match allow-clear="true" placeholder="Select country">
            {{$select.selected.name}}
      </ui-select-match>
      <ui-select-choices repeat="country in countries | filter: $select.search">
            <span ng-bind-html="country.name | highlight: $select.search"></span>
            <small ng-bind-html="country.code | highlight: $select.search"></small>
      </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer @lin. It helped me to fix more than 12 issues in my project.