# AngularJS remove ng-options blank value

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-options

```
<select ng-model="form.priority" ng-options="priority.id as priority.value for priority in leadPriority"></select>
```

It is showing blank option by default. How can remove it ?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738953/angular-js-remove-blank-option-from-select-option). You can set in the controller as `$scope.form.priority = $scope.leadPriority[0].id;`

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-init in options
eg.

```
<select ng-model="form.priority" ng-options="priority.id as priority.value for priority in leadPriority" ng-init="form.priority = leadPriority[0].id"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set in the controller as,

```
$scope.form.priority = $scope.leadPriority[0].id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ui-select which is more powerful version of select. You can find sample code for it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750074/angularjs-ui-select-once-selected-not-able-to-remove-selected-option-apart-from). You will need to include the js and css file from their library [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/tree/master/dist).